# Sketching power function for a log normal density

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

**Question:**

[image]

Hello,

I am attempting all parts of the attached question. I have done part a, b and c.

I have 2 questions.

For part b)

I am not quite sure what it means to "argue" that there is a UMP test of size alpha? I know to exhibit its structure we just do the usual 1 if T(x)> some constant and 0 if T(x) < some constant.

For part d)

I did $$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(X_i)^2}>k\right)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i^2>k\right)=P(\chi_n^2>k)$$
And this makes $$k=\chi_{n,\alpha}^2 $$
So my test is $$\psi=\begin{cases}1 \text{ if} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i>\chi_{n,\alpha}^2 \\
0 \text { if } \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i<\chi_{n,\alpha}^2 \end{cases}$$

Now my question is, have i done question d right? Also, I am not sure how to calculate the power function and subsequently sketch it.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a connection between part (a) and part (b) that explains the existence of UMP test. You should be working with $\sum (\ln X_i)^2$ instead and identify which statistic has a $\chi^2_n$ distribution. And finally, where do you have difficulty finding power function? It is just the probability of rejection of $H_0$ under $\theta$.

Comment: Did you mean that instead of using ln(X_i) i should have used ln(X_i)^2 because i realized i forgot to add the square and edited the question. As for the power function, how do you sketch the probability that chi sqaured is > a constant? Normally, I would expect to get something like $$\alpha(1/t)^n$$ which i can sketch, but i don't know how to sketch the former.

Comment: There are still typos. And $\sum (\ln X_i)^2$ has to be scaled properly to have a $\chi^2_n$ distribution. Have you done any theorem/result linking monotone likelihood ratio property and UMP tests? Check your notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is monotone likelihood ratio in $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\ln X_i)^2$, it can be argued by Karlin-Rubin theorem that $\phi=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }T>c \\ 0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$ is a UMP test for testing $H_0$ against $H_1$.

Now $T/\theta^2\sim \chi^2_n$ and size of the test is $\alpha$, so that

$$E_{\theta_0}\,\phi=P_{\theta_0}[T>c]=P_{\theta_0}\left[\frac{T}{\theta_0^2}>\frac{c}{\theta_0^2}\right]=P\left[\chi^2_n>\frac{c}{\theta_0^2}\right]=\alpha$$

This gives $$\frac{c}{\theta_0^2}=\chi^2_{n,\alpha}\,,\text{ i.e. }\, c=\theta_0^2\chi^2_{n,\alpha}$$

As for the power function, you have

\begin{align}
E_{\theta}\,\phi&=P_{\theta}\left[T>\theta_0^2\chi^2_{n,\alpha}\right]
\\&=P_{\theta}\left[\frac{T}{\theta^2}>\frac{\theta_0^2\chi^2_{n,\alpha}}{\theta^2}\right]
\\&=P\left[\chi^2_n>\frac{\theta_0^2\chi^2_{n,\alpha}}{\theta^2}\right]
\end{align}

Try to show that this is an increasing function of $\theta$. Further argue that $E_{\theta}\,\phi<\alpha$ for $\theta<\theta_0$ and $E_{\theta}\,\phi>\alpha$ for $\theta>\theta_0$. Using this information, you can provide a rough sketch for power function.